# Regression variables integrated of orders I(0), I(1) and I(2)

Tags: time-series, vector-error-correction-model, ardl

I am working on a model with 4 variables, and these variables are integrated I(0) and I(1), but one variable is integrated I(2). What is the model suitable for this data?

Comment: You should take the first difference of the I(2) variable. After that, you have a system of I(0) and I(1) variables. I have answered many questions about such systems. For starters, check out [these](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=I%280%29+I%281%29+integrated+cointegrated) threads, and then you may modify the search to find more.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer

Comment: I understood the procedure well